# How can I disable window resizing in a Xamarin.Mac Cocoa app?

Tags: c#, xcode, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am building a `Xamarin.Mac Cocoa` application and designing the storyboard and views in Xcode. And I would like to **disable view resizing** to prevent the user from changing the size of the windows.

Comment: Uncheck Resize of the window?

Comment: Could you please show where that is? With a screenshot on Xcode maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select "Window" in the Window Controller Scene hierarchy tree and then in the "Attributes" pane, deselect "Resize" control.

[image]